# archivos dinamicos en c#,

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chrome

Tengo un problema, algo tan sencillo como un boton, que crea una nueva fila en una tabla, cuando ejecuto mi proyecto y presiono el boton, se ve rapidamente que si crea la fila, pero despues se recarga la pagina y al final de mi ruta del proyecto me pone un '?'

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
function btn() {

 document.getElementById("table").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >+</button></td><td contenteditable="true">x</td><td contenteditable="true">x</td><td contenteditable="true">x</td><td contenteditable="true">x</td>';
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-12 ml-auto">
                                        <button id="enviar" class="btn btn-success" onclick="btn()" style="float:right;">x</button>
                                    </div>
 <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width:10px;">colum1</th>
                                            <th style="width:10px;">colum2</th>
                                            <th style="width:10px;">colum3</th>
                                            <th style="width:10px;">colum4</th>
                                            <th style="width:10px;">colum5</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="table">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>                                            
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando doy click, se recarga se pone lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo mas, habilite los scripts en visual studio, y cuando pongo un break point en en contenido de la function btn(), cuando doy click si entra y se ve que crea la fila, cuando doy continuar, empieza abrir scripts dinamicos, se igual manera la pagina se actualiza y sucede lo que ya comente, ademas si comento tal function btn, sucede los mismo aun estando comentado,

como puedo solucionar esto?

nota:se que en este ejemplo funciona perfectamente, no se si es visual o chrome que me genera este conflicto

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema es que esta haciendo *post back*,
agrégale a tu etiqueta del botón un:

```
type="button"
```

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, puedes copiar todo el codigo de la pregunta y crear el codigo correcto para comprobar, o en lugar de respuesta agrega lo que dices como comentario

Comment: Los votos son secretos por algun motivo... y es justamente para eso. podrias mirar [answer] y por ejemplo, ejemplificar donde poner eso, para que la proxima persona que vea tu respuesta, entienda donde va escrito eso, y porque va ahi?

Comment: esta explicado ahi nada mas que son bien llorones en este foro, por eso me gusta mas el americano, donde no te dicen tanta lloriconeria, ahi dice el problema es que estas haciendo post back, agregale a tu etiqueta del boton un type="button", no entiendo donde no esta explicado lo que comentan, incluso la marco como respuesta, pero tienen siempre que opinar sus opiniones de gente que se cree superior